# Echo variable into file

Tags: bash, variables, yum, repository

I wrote my own repo file and am attempting to script the installation in bash.

My code:

```
echo -e "[repo name]\nname=repo - $serverver - $basearch...\n.." >> /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo
```

However when I run the command the `$serverver` and `$basearch` are missing.

How can I echo the variables into the file with out it trying to determine them?

I have attempted

```
echo -E

"$serverver"

'$serverver'

`$serverver`

\"$serverver\"
```

Comment: Are `serverver` and `basearch` defined?

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable; it's better to use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

To add to `yum.repos.d` use single quotes`'` instead of double`"`. That preserves the `$` signs as it is which is later interpreted by `yum`.

```
echo -e '[repo name]\nname=repo - $serverver - $basearch...\n..' >> /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e "[repo name]\nname=repo - \$serverver - \$basearch...\n.." >> /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo
```

$ denotes shell variable expansion. If you want a literal $ it has to be escaped, as above, or you must use single quotes. If you want to expand shell variables they must be defined, or else they will yield the empty string.